# JSONP array undefined outside of function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, jsonp

I found a lot of questions similar to mine; but none of the answers I saw seemed to work for me.  So here is my issue.  I am using jQuery JSONP to obtain quite a bit of information on some books (the JSON is static so it has a hardcoded function wrapped around it).  I have this working great.  My problem is that I need to reference the JSON several more times and with it being static I figured I needed to set a local array with the values.  So here is my code below:

```
function changeList(cat) {
  getList(cat);
}
var bookArray = new Array();

function parseResponse(jsonData) {
  $('#bookList').empty();
  var items = [];
  var p = '0';
  $.each(jsonData, function(item, i) {
    bookArray[p] = { 'bookId':i.bookId, 'category':i.category, 'publishedDate':i.publishedDate, 'title':i.title, 'description':i.description, 'images':i.images };

    var allImages = i.images;
    if(allImages.length > 1) {
      var imageLoc = allImages.toString().split(",");
    } else {
      var imageLoc = new Array(allImages);
    }
    var theDate = new Date();
    theDate.setTime(i.publishedDate * 1000);
    var year  = theDate.getUTCFullYear(); 
    var month = theDate.getUTCMonth();
    var day = theDate.getUTCDate();
    var d = months[month] + " " + day + ", " + year;

    items.push('<li><a href="/' + i.category + '/' + i.bookId + '/index.html"><img border="0" height="70" width="124" src="' + imageLoc[0] + '"><p>Published: <strong>' + d + '</strong><br /><span class="bookTitle">' + i.title + '</span> ' + i.description + '</p></a></li>');
    p++;
  });

  $('<ul/>', {
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('#bookList');
}

function getList(section) {
  $.getJSON('http://www.otherdomain.com/book_'+ section +'.json?format=jsonp&callback=?', function(data) { });
}
```

What the snippet of code above does is spits out a list of books from a certain cateogry on the page.  There is a menu on the left that has the categories and fires the changeList() function (which in turn triggers the other functions to draw the correct json and spit them out on the page).  This part works flawlessly!

Which brings me to my issue, as you can see in the parseResponse() function I am populating the 'bookArray' array that I created.  If I reference that array inside the function I have no issues.  However, if I try to reference it outside (for example alert(bookArray[0]['title']) I get that it is undefined.  What am I doing wrong?  I'm not the most tech savy person, so you have to use small words on me.  Thanks for any help!

**EDIT** 
Here is a snippet to give you an idea of what the JSON file looks like:

```
parseResponse(
[{
        "bookId":"1",
        "category":"A",
        "publishedDate":"1266870137",
        "title":"Title to first story",
        "description":"The first story.",
        "images":["http://www.otherdomian.com/books/fff.jpg","http://www.otherdomian.com/books/aaa.jpg"]
    },{
        "bookId":"2",
        "category":"A",
        "publishedDate":"1366870142",
        "title":"Title to second story",
        "description":"The second story.",
        "images":["http://www.otherdomian.com/books/fff.jpg","http://www.otherdomian.com/books/aaa.jpg"]
    }
])
```

Comment: Are you declaring var bookArray somewhere? Where is it being used that it is undefined. Am I right saying that this is an issue with varable scope and not your json?

Comment: bookArray is declared on line 4 of my snippet above.  I haven't used it yet as to test I tried to use alert and it was undefined.  In the bottom of the HTML of the page I also tried a document.write with no luck.

Comment: One more stupid question from me. Did you call parseResponse before trying to access the contents of bookArray?

Comment: Yeah, parseResponse is called when I load the JSON.  All the scripting you see above is in the head of my HTML page.  My test I tried to access in like my page footer.  The issue has something to do with calling outside the function.  As if I do alert(bookArray[0]['title']) inside the function I get what I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getList(section) {
    $.getJSON('http://www.otherdomain.com/book_'+ section +'.json?format=jsonp&callback=?', parseResponse);
}
```

AJAX calls are asynchronous and so you can't start working with the data before the request completes. This sets `parseResponse` as a callback, which means that it gets called after the request completes. At this point you'll have your json.

If you want to access the data outside, you have to make sure that you do it after the callback completes, which means any other code that needs to use it further needs to be called *from* your callback.

```
var bookArray = []; //use this instead of new Array(). There are security issues with the former (Array can be overridden)

function parseResponse(jsonData) {

   /*
     ... existing code ...
   */

   otherFunctionThatNeedsBookArray(); //alternatively you can set bookArray as a local variable and call otherFunctionThatNeedsBookArray(bookArray);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this will have to do.  It's not going to be pretty, but I suppose that is what I get being stuck using HTML and JavaScript only.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe becouse p is defined as a String `p='0'`. Try `p=0;`

Comment: Still no luck, I had tried that.  I also tried using bookArray[item] and bookArray['item'] with no luck.  I read on some other questions you had to do the counter separately which is why I have the p in there.

Comment: In which moment are You using the parseResponse function? Is it possible, that You write the whole code in http://jsbin.com/?

Comment: parseResponse is wrapped around the json so that JSONP works.

Answer (score 0):

This first bit isn't the answer to your question, but you have your jQuery.each() parameters the wrong way round I think, in that 'i' should be your index and 'item' should be the value. I may be mistaken, but you then should be able to use i instead of p to index your array

Comment: from what I can tell they are interchangeable, as if I do alert(item) it sends out a 0,1,2,3,etc....

Comment: I would think 'i' would be the index and 'item' would be the object, but it appears you use them correctly despite how they are named.

Comment: OK - I thought from the jQuery docs (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) that the first param is the index, the second the item. I agree that you're using them correctly, I just thought that the names were misleading. Have you tried using either of them as the index in bookArray instead of p?

Comment: Yes, as I commented in @czerasz post below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark. Your title suggests you are using a JSONP ajax request which is ALWAYS asynchronous. I'm guessing that you are trying to access your global variable's contents before the JSONP request responds. In jQuery it would be appropriate to access the data from within the 'success' callback.

Comment: Ok, so how would I go about doing that?

Comment: The most common solution is to use setInterval to poll if a function within the script exists, and when it does, it is considered done loading. That's why a JSONP response is a callback, typically having a name with a random number to avoid collisions. The callback would return an object containing your array.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is basically what @Vivin was saying.